# How can I modify this code to iterate the matrices n times?

Tags: numpy, math, matrix

I need to iterate to matrices n number of times, and I have this code:

```
  import numpy as np 

  mat1 = ([1, 6, 5],[3 ,4, 8],[2, 12, 3]) 
  mat2 = ([3, 4, 6],[5, 6, 7],[6,56, 7])   
  res = np.dot(mat1,mat2) 
  print(res)
```

I would like to know how to modify this code to iterate two matrices n number of times.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: By "iterate", do you mean "multiply the result by one of the matrices n times"? Such as `C = A * B * B * B * B * B * ... * B`?

Comment: I'm working with Markov Chains so I would like to multiply my transitional matrix by the current state matrix, and in each iteration (multiplication) save the new value of the current state as the one to multiply by the transitional matrix.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is multiply your matrix inside of a loop:

```
stateMatrix = ([...], ...)
transitionalMatrix = ([...], ...)
maxIterations = n

res = [stateMatrix]
for iteration in range(1, maxIterations):
  prev = res[iteration - 1]
  res.append(prev.matmul(transitionalMatrix))
# res[i] contains the state matrix at step i.
```

`res[-1]` will contain the final state matrix, and you can see every step it took to get there by examining the other elements of `res`.

Comment: When executing the code, it appears the message "list object has no attribute matlub". I'm working with NumPy version 1.17.5.

Comment: @B.Casals Looks like you made a typo somewhere.

Comment: I just copied the code exacly as provided.                                                 
    import numpy as np

   transitionalMatrix = ([0.78, 0.05, 0.15, 0.02],[0.07 ,0.82, 0.01, 0.1], [0.10, 
   0.04, 0.84, 0.01], [0, 0.11, 0, 0.89]) 
   stateMatrix = ([0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.10]) 
   maxIterations = 20

   res = [stateMatrix]
   for iteration in range(1, maxIterations):
   prev = res[iteration - 1]
   res.append(prev.matmul(transitionalMatrix))

Comment: It appears to be that "matmul" function doesn't exist. How can I solve it?